# How to move an array of objects in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have created two models in nodejs, which are: `User` and `Auth`.

In the User model will be stored the user name and an array of authentication objects that is reference of the Auth model.

In the Auth model will be stored the token generated by JWT and the creation date of the token ...

**Rules:**
Each user can have multiple authentication token, but each token will be unique as soon as the token expires, it will be aborted in the database, but the creation date should remain.

**What's my problem?**

**1) I'm having cast problem in Array.**

**2) I do not know how to go through this Array of Objects, starting with the auth token and the specific username.**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

class AuthModel {
    createSchema(){
        const authSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
            token: {
                type:     String,
                unique:   true,
                required: true
            },
            createAt: {
                type:    Date,
                default: Date.now
            }
        });

        return authSchema;
    }
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('AuthModel', new AuthModel().createSchema());

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

class UserModel {
    createSchema(){
        const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
            username: {
                type:     String,
                unique:   true,
                required: true
            },
            createdAt: {
                type:    Date,
                default: Date.now
            },
            auth: [{
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'AuthModel',
                required: true,
            }]
        });

        return userSchema;
    }
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('UserModel', new UserModel().createSchema());
```

Comment: what kind of cast problems are you having?

Comment: @0.sh 
I send to the user creation route the name of it and an array of objects with the tokens .. And it gives CAST error in the array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
   1: //define embedded schema    
    const authSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
                  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'AuthModel',
                    required: true,
       });
      const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
                username: {
                    type:     String,
                    unique:   true,
                    required: true
                },
                createdAt: {
                    type:    Date,
                    default: Date.now
                },
                auth: [authSchema]   // add embedded schema here  
            });
 2 .  When you fetch userModel, you will be required to populate( mongoose function) auth model
```